How can I resolve this issue: /lib64/libm.so.6:/lib64/libm.so.6:version `GLIBC_2.29`not found
libm.so error, glibc cannot be upgraded, how to solve this problem
uname -a
Linux iZ2zehv8dwkdvggyua79p2Z 4.19.0-91.82.141.6.uelc20.aarch64 #1 SMP Thu May 25 11:37:10 CST 2023 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux

ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.28
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

I read this Q&A and tried upgrading glibc, but it didn't help
How can I resolve this issue: libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.29' not found, C/C++?

What are you trying to do? What OS are you on? What build system are you using? How are you linking to libm.so?

looks like you're trying to link libraries built with a newer version of glibc. Don't attempt to upgrade glibc, you'll just end up breaking your OS. If you need a newer version of libc you'll need to update your whole OS. Which OS are you using? What are you trying to build?

My IDE requires configuration of the Java runtime environment（https://github.com/JetBrains/JetBrainsRuntime）, which depends on JCEF（https://github.com/JetBrains/jcef）. However, there is an error with this dependency on my Linux system.

The build of the software you are trying to install requires a newer Linux distribution than the one that you are using. Either you need to upgrade your Linux installation to a newer version (e.g. if you're still on Ubuntu 18.04, upgrade to e.g. 20.04), or you need to find a version of your software that has been built for older Linux distributions that will still run on your system. (glibc 2.29 was released in the beginning of 2019.)
